# Eclipse/Mylyn: use JIRA and Bitbucket?

Tags: eclipse, jira, bitbucket, mylyn

It is possible to connect a Bitbucket account to JIRA: http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/04/30/linking-bitbucket-and-jira/

But is it possible to connect them using Eclipse/Mylyn?

Answer (score 1):

Atlassian have a connector for Eclipse and JIRA which you can check out here: http://www.atlassian.com/software/ide-connectors/overview. It manages builds, source control, issues, etc, etc. Well worth a look.

Comment: The IDE Connector connects JIRA to Eclipse, but doesn't connect a Bitbucket repo in Eclipse.

Comment: If that is the case, I would suggest that you look into using EGit for Eclipse. If that is the sort of solution you're looking for, let me know and I will pad out and edit my original answer to reflect this.